I have an android gallery app and when i play a video it works fine on pixel 3a but on galaxy s23 it shows a black screen but sound works
public class VideoPlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private VideoView videoView;
private MediaController mediaController;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_player);

    videoView = findViewById(R.id.videoView);

    String videoPath = getIntent().getStringExtra("videoPath");
    videoView.setVideoPath(videoPath);
    mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.start();
}

}
Google pixel 3a is running on android 12 and the Samsung s23 is running on android 14 I tried the same video on both devices and it works fine on the pixel but on shows a blank screen on the Samsung but the sound and the controls work. Also tried recording a video with H.264 and still the same problem. Any ideas of how to get it to work or a third party library that might work I tried exoplayer also and I got the same problem.


Did you try to look for errors in the Logcat? 2. Where is the video path from? 3. You are supposed to wait until the ViewView is prepared before starting.


I figured it out had to add this line in "videoView.setZOrderOnTop(true);"

Had to add setZOrderOnTop
    videoView = findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    String videoPath = getIntent().getStringExtra("videoPath");
    videoView.setVideoPath(videoPath);

    mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
    videoView.start();

